# why do I get react-native command not found error on windows pc?

Tags: react-native

I am very new to React-native and I have a sample project when I tried running the command react-native run-android. I got an error command not found.

Comment: Have you tried npm i -g react-native-cli ?

Comment: yes, I installed it.

Comment: 1.Try to install globally npm install -g react-native-cli 2.add path of npm module (C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\npm) to system variables instead of user variables

Comment: Are you inside the project folder where node modules are present?

Comment: I don't get error for ionic

Answer (score 3):

in the current directory do

```
react-native -v
```

you will get the following

```
react-native -v
react-native-cli: version
react-native: version
```

if it shows command not found the n you have not installed react native in the directory. Do a npm init in new folder and try installing a new react native project there 
by doing `npm install -g react-native-cli` 
Follow the steps to add path variable react-native.

You're good to go.

Comment: I get the same error when I run the command also I have added path as below: - C:\Users\WIN10\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: U just cannot add path to the env variable. The path may differ for different installations.  check this path C:\Users\WIN10\AppData\Roaming\npm if npm actually exixts in this path or not. If not check other folder in app data which points to npm

Comment: npm exsists in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

Have you run '`npm install`' (without parameters) in the project directory? That'll install the dependencies for your project.

Details here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1.Try to install globally npm install -g react-native-cli 2.add path of npm module (C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\npm) to system variables instead of user variables

Comment: Run this command whether  your npm pointing  to correct location or not.            npm config list ( or) Try to unistall and install back the node again.

Comment: $ npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v10.13.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\WIN10\.npmrc
prefix = "c:\\Users\\WIN10\\Downloads\\react-native-rtmpVideoPlayer-master\\react-native-rtmpVideoPlayer-master\\'npm-global'"

; builtin config undefined

; node bin location = c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = c:\Users\WIN10\Downloads\react-native-rtmpVideoPlayer-master\react-native-rtmpVideoPlayer-master
; HOME = C:\Users\WIN10
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.